# React nested Context Providers Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events, react-context

I have an issue while using several ContextProviders and don't know how to fix this.

I have nested providers like this:

```js
function App(){
  return (
    <Context1Provider>
      <Context2Provider>
        Hello World!
      </Context2Provider>
    </Context1Provider>
  )
}
```

`Context1Provider` has function in `value` which needs to be accessed by `Context2Provider`

`Context2Provider` has function in `value` which needs to be accessed by `Context1Provider`

Long story short, They need cross access each other's values.

For Example:
If I have `AuthContextProvider` and `UserDataProvider` auth data is depending on `UserDataProvider` and `UserDataProvider` needs to fire function from `AuthContextProvider`.

Is it correct if I will add global `eventListeners` to `window` object?

```
window.addEventListener('onAuthStateChange', handler);
window.addEventListener('onUserDataChange', handler);
```

If not, can you suggest correct design pattern?

P.S.: I Can't unificate Providers

Comment: Is there any suggestion?

Comment: You need a parent context to hold the data which is common to context 1 and context 2. Context 1 and context 2 both then access the data from the new (parent) context.