# Passing data between react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, signalr, react-context

I'm having troubles passing data from one context to the other in React. I have some job data that is received from a SignalR connection and I need to pass it to a specific job context, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I have the following code:

##### SignalRContext

```js
export interface SignalRContextProps {
  connect: () => void;
}

export const SignalRContext = createContext<SignalRContextProps>(null!);

export const useSignalRContext = (): SignalRContextProps => {
  const {onProgressReceived} = useContext(JobsContext);

  const connect = () => {
    //Removed a lot of connection setup code for readability
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().build();
    connection.on('JobReportProgress', onProgressReceived);
    connection.start();
  };

  return {
    connect,
  };
};
```

##### SignalRContextProvider

```js
type Props = {
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
}

export const SignalRContextProvider = (props: Props) => {
  const {children} = props;
  const signalRContext = useSignalRContext();

  return (
    <SignalRContext.Provider value={signalRContext}>
      {children}
    </SignalRContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

##### JobsContext

```js
export const JobsContext = createContext<JobsContextProps>(null!);

export const useJobsContext = (): JobsContextProps => {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState<Job[]>([]);

  const load = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const jobs = await getAllJobs();
    setJobs(jobs);
  };

  const onProgressReceived = (progress: JobProgress) => {
    console.log(jobs);
    const currentJob = jobs.find((job) => job.id === progress.id);
    console.log(currentJob); //currentJob will always be empty because jobs array is NULL on receiving progress.
    }
  };

  return {
    load, onProgressReceived, jobs
  };
};
```

##### JobsContextProvider

```js
interface Props {
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
}

export const JobsContextProvider = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
  const {children} = props;
  const jobsContext = useJobsContext();

  return (
    <JobsContext.Provider value={jobsContext}>
      {children}
    </JobsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

##### index

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <JobsContextProvider>
    <SignalRContextProvider>
      <App />
    </SignalRContextProvider>
  </JobsContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

#### Flow

1. In my app.tsx I start the SignalR connection by calling `signalRContext.connect()` created by `const signalRContext = useContext(SignalRContext);`
2. I go to my job page where my 6 jobs are loaded from the backend via my context

```
const {load} = useContext(JobsContext);
await load();
```

3. I trigger a job and I see that the SignalR context is calling onProgressReceived on the jobContext. But for some reason the jobs array is empty so I can't update the correct job. Is seems that a new context is created instead of reusing the existing context.

Anyone has an idea how I can make my SignalRContext pass data to my JobContext? Or maybe there is a better system that using context for this?

#### UPDATE 1:

I have the feeling that there is something strange going on with the HubConnection instance. When I register my 'onProgressReceived' function as a callback function on the 'JobReportProgress' event then it doesn't work. But when I first save the progress with setState and trigger the 'onProgressReceived' function with useEffect it seems to be working. Small example:

```js
const {jobs, onProgressReceived} = useContext(JobsContext);
const [progress, setProgress] = useState<JobProgress | null>(null);

//Change the connection.on line with the following
connection.on('JobReportProgress', onReceived);

//And then we trigger the function on change
const onReceived = (progress: JobProgress) => {
  setProgress(progress);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (progress !== null) {
    onProgressReceived(progress);
  }
}, [progress]);
```

This seems to be working, but not sure why I first need to save my progress with useState.

Answer (score 0):

I had very same issue a while ago. I even asked question about it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675923/react-nested-context-providers-issue)
There are ways to connect nested context to each other, but then code gets messy.

1. At first I used event listeners and was dispatching events when some data received, but didn't worked well.
2. Then I tried passing `callbacks` in context `value`. Pass callback from `JobsContextProvider` ex: `onSignalData` and call this `callback` when data is updated in `SignalRContextProvider` and save in `JobsContextProvider`.
3. Combined these 2 contexts into one and it worked well, but didn't liked it as well. Code got messy.
4. Then I give up using contexts in this type of data and used `redux` with [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and [RTK Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview). It works very vell, code is well organized and this is the best solution I have found so far.

Let me know in comments which solution works best for you and I can write exact pseudocode for that solution.